# Записать данные с поля одной таблицы в поле другой таблицы php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

я изучаю php не так давно поэтому прошу извинить за такой глупый вопрос. Суть вопроса в том что у меня есть две таблицы в БД одна называется news с полями (id,image,title,text,pubdate,views), а другая называется comment с полями (id,news_id,name,text pubdate) и я не могу понять как мне вывести коментарии для каждой отдельной новости. Я делаю запрос в виде $sqa = "SELECT * FROM comment  WHERE news_id = '$id'"; Где $id эта переменная id news я не могу понять как мне записать  в news_id данные id с таблицы news. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Так запрос не сработает, это просто тестовая строка. Начните отсюда http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно где-то хранить `id` новости, например в супер-глобальной переменной `$_GET` или `$_POST` при загрузке страницы с новостью, и когда добавляешь новый комментарий, то в `news_id` берёшь значение из `$_GET['id']` или `$_POST['id']`.

Конечно GET-запрос будет проще сделать, например, `yoursite.com/news.php?id=1`, при этом в `$_GET['id']` будет храниться `1` и запрос будет выглядеть `'SELECT * FROM comment WHERE news_id = $_GET['id']'`.

И да, такой запрос уязвим для `SQL-инъекций`, поэтому лучше почитай [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php) по подготавливаемым запросам.

UPD: Если новостей на странице несколько, то в блоке с каждой новостью (`<div>`, например) можно добавить атрибут `id`, в котором будет храниться айдишник твоей записи. Пример `<div id="100500"><p>Новость<p></div>`

Comment: Большое спасибо